# Having issue with push(''/') what could be wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, connected-react-router

I am using the connected react router for routing in my project. It seems to work as expected unless I use push('/'). This does not change the URL. If i remove exact from the route definition it changes the content shown to be what I want but not the URL.

The project versions I am using are:

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"connected-react-router": "^6.9.2"
```

What could be causing the issue?

Edit: here is a sample of my configuration.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <OidcProvider store={store} userManager={userManager}>
                <AppContextProvider>
                    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={10}>
                            <Layout>
                                <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                                        <Route path="/callback" component={CallbackPage} />
                                        <Route path="/user" component={Users} />
                                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                                        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                                        <Route path="/account" component={MyAccount} />
                                        <Route path="/userdetails/:id" component={UserPage} />
                                    </Switch>
                                </ConnectedRouter>
                            </Layout>
                        </SnackbarProvider>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </AppContextProvider>
            </OidcProvider>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: Can you add some code around where you are calling `push('/')`? Where does the push function come from?

Comment: Its from the connected-react-router library found here: https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router

Comment: Can you supply some code?

Comment: You will probably need to use the `useNavigate` hook since `useHistory` has been removed from React Router 6

Comment: Because I am using the connected-react-router I am using the push functions which replaces the use of userHistory

Comment: @LyndenNoye added some code.